# Adding .class to <li> elements according to their width, but their width also changes after adding .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**You can see the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/6gnAF/1/**

I've little problem with my list elements.

I'm using very simple unordered list like;

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='button'>Element 1</li>
    ...
    <li class='button'>Element N</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(Number of list elements, N, varies on every page.)

The `div` which contains the `ul` is `696 px` width. List elements, `li`, are horizontally aligned, and when they reach end of div's width, they contiues on new line.

What I wanted to adding class `.left` the first `li` of every line, and class `.right` to the last one.

```
    $('li').each(function() {
        var liWidthOut = $(this).width();
        totalWidth += liWidthOut;
        if (totalWidth >= divWidth) {
            $(this).addClass("left");
            $(this).prev().removeClass("middle").addClass("right");
            totalWidth = liWidthOut;
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("middle");
        }
     });
```

I managed that with Jquery, but I've a little problem.

**You can see the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/6gnAF/1/**

**The problem is**, `.left` and `.right` classes change the width of `li` elements which are added to, so some times they create new lines, and last li elements become first one which have `.right` class, instead of `.left`.

How can I fix this?

*(Sorry for the grammatically errors)*

Comment: The width of you `li` isn't changing when you add the `.left` or `.right` class.

Comment: You can see that they change. I've added a button that triggers the code instead of it happening instantly. http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/6gnAF/4/

Comment: Can't you just make it so that the font size is the same before and after?

Comment: If you change the Sportway button class to middle, it does go back to the correct position. Its width is not changing.

Comment: @MattBurland it is changing as lbstr mentioned.

Comment: @Asad there're plenty of lists, manually changing class for each list element is not possible.

Comment: That was a typo. I meant to write it does **not** go back to the correct position. Your problem statement is incorrect. See Nelson's answer for what the problem actually was.

Comment: @Asad, you're right. I tought that `li` elements move into next line, instead of getting wrong class.

Comment: @Turcia: I looked at the width before and after applying the `.left` and `.right` classes. They don't change (at least in FF). As Nelson identified, the problem is the button class that you add at the very end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is mostly right, just two nitpicks which made it go wrong:

1. Use `var liWidthOut = this.offsetWidth;` instead of `var liWidthOut =
   $(this).width();` as the later is giving you the width of the inner
   text, instead of also adding the padding, as `offsetWidth` does.
2. Apply the `.button` class before starting looping and calculating
   widths, as the `.button` style will affect the elements width, you have to
   apply it in the first place so your calculations don't fail later.

See [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/6gnAF/16/) of your code with those two things corrected.

Comment: +1 for identifying the actual problem, although I think Jan's approach is just generally more reliable than the original.

Answer (score 5):

I changed the method to tracking the `top` position instead of calculating widths, seems to work ok. Using `width()` with paddings and borders and whatnot is less than reliable.

```
$('li')
    // Add classes first, so we calculate on the right styles
    .addClass("middle")
    .addClass("button")
    .each(function() {
        // Compare with last position
        if (lastPos != $(this).position().top) {
            $(this).removeClass("middle").addClass("left")
                .prev().removeClass("middle").addClass("right");
        }
        // Store last position
        lastPos = $(this).position().top;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qydM/6/

Comment: thanks. Since, I've forced to accept ONE answer, I selected Nelson's one which is fix my code... In the big picture, the code in your answer is better than mine, I'll use it.

Comment: Yeah, I could have done a better job at describing the issue. For the record, `$(this).outerWidth()` will also work (which you'd already tried). The real error in your logic was that you didn't apply the classes until after the loop, that's why I included that as a comment in my script.

Comment: IF I would have used that approach I'd have done something like `if ($(this).parent().width() < $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth())` and an `overflow-x:hidden` or somesuch on the container, also a bit more reliable than your original method which doesn't account for space inbetween elements. Anyways, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to separate these lists into seperate lists?

If so you could use [:nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) or [:last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

Comment: It's possible but it is not convenient since there're tons of different lists.